# Reading some xlsx file in a loop

Tags: r, xlsx

I have a dataframe that has a column which contains xlsx file names in each row,I want to read each row in r and then add a column to that an save it again, so for this goal I write a loop like :
u = data.frame(V1 = c("a", "b","c"),stringsAsFactors = F )

```
for(i in 1:nrow(u) ){
  #file name
  dir = paste(u$V1[1], "_",i , ".xlsx" , sep="")
  #reading the file: the problem is here 
  file<-read.xlsx(dir,1)
  #making it as a dataframe
  file.df<-as.data.frame(downloaded.file)
  #Column which will added to the data
  b <- u$V1[i]
  #Adding a column
  result<-cbind(b,file.df)
  # File name
  dir = paste("res" , i , ".txt" , sep="")
  # Writing the result
  write.table(result , file = dir , sep = "\t")
  # Counting the list
  print(i)}
```

The problem is that when it doesn't find a file,shows an error and comes out from the loop.But I want it to go to the next row instead.For this I wrote an if clause like

```
if (file != 0)
      next
```

but it couldn't help me. Any idea to fix the problem?

Comment: something like `file.exists("snack")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
u = data.frame(V1 = c("a", "b","c"),stringsAsFactors = F )
require(xlsx)

for(i in 1:nrow(u) ){
  #file name
  files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.xls") # gets both xls and xlsx
  dir = paste(u$V1[1], "_",i , ".xlsx" , sep="")
  #reading the file: the solution is here 
  if(dir %in% files){
    file<-read.xlsx(dir,1)
    #making it as a dataframe
    file.df<-as.data.frame(downloaded.file)
    #Column which will added to the data
    b <- u$V1[i]
    #Adding a column
    result<-cbind(b,file.df)
    # File name
    dir = paste("res" , i , ".txt" , sep="")
    # Writing the result
    write.table(result , file = dir , sep = "\t")
    # Counting the list
    print(i)
  }
}
```